# Removing class for parent div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have `<div>` structure in the following way:

```
<div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin">
    <span class="fc-event-title">
        <div class="removeBackGround"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

So, using jQuery how do I find and remove the parent class(fc-event-inner fc-event-skin) using "removeBackGround" class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.removeBackGround').parents('.fc-event-inner,.fc-event-skin').removeClass('fc-event-inner fc-event-skin');
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove the class use the following code:

```
$(".removeBackGround")
    .closest("div")
    .removeClass("fc-event-inner fc-event-skin");
```

Check [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t know how many levels up it is, use `.closest()`

```
$('.removeBackGround').closest('.fc-event-skin').removeClass('fc-event-inner fc-event-skin');
```

If you know it’s always two levels up you can chain parents:

```
$('.removeBackGround').parent().parent().removeClass('fc-event-inner fc-event-skin');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.removeBackGround').closest('.fc-event-inner fc-event-skin').remove();
```

or you can go with this

```
$('.removeBackGround').parents('.fc-event-inner,.fc-event-skin').removeClass('fc-event-inner fc-event-skin');
```

Answer (score 1):

***try this***

```
$('.removeBackGround').parentsUntil('.fc-event-inner.fc-event-skin').parent().attr('class','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to this as like

```
$('p').removeClass('myClass yourClass')
```

more info ***[link](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)***

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to do that. But,

```
$(".removeBackGround").closest('div.fc-event-inner,div.fc-event-skin').removeClass("fc-event-inner fc-event-skin");
```

would work best.