# how to remove the class on clicking a button and adding new class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

suppose there is a div with class "box" on clicking the button with class "button" I want to remove the class "box" from the div and add a absolutely new class "active" to the div. what will be the jQuery code of the following?

html

```
 <div class="box">
 <button class="button">button</button>
 </div>
```

and also how should I add the new class in CSS ? like normally we add.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make an effort and show some code. This is not a new topic, so there's lots to read on SO.

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046879/remove-class-from-parent-element-with-jquery/16046901, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296329/removing-class-for-parent-div-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeClass` method to remove class and use `addClass` method to add class using jquery.

You can also chain method as:

```
box.removeClass("box").addClass("active");
```

```js
const box = $(".box");

$(".button").on("click", function() {
  box.removeClass("box");
  box.addClass("active");
})
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good time to take advantage of jquery's chaining.

Comment: @freedomn-m nice catch, thanks for suggestion and updated the code. 

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the easiest way is to use the [`classList.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method which you can use with both jQuery, and vanilla JS.

jQuery.

```js
$('.button').click(function () {
  const parent = this.parentNode;
  parent.classList.replace('box', 'active');
});
```

```css
.active { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Vanilla JS.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  const parent = this.parentNode;
  parent.classList.replace('box', 'active');
}
```

```css
.active { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest jQuery technique is probably with `toggle`:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('box active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #ddd;
}

.active {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```